# Get info about something itself

Tags: c#

I have this mistery:

```
public class UIWindow : Control
{
    public PythonDictionary Variables;
    public PythonTuple Children
    {
        get
        {
            if(Variables.has_key("children"))
                return (PythonTuple)Variables["children"];

            return null;
        }
    }

    public UIWindow(PythonDictionary variables)
    {
        Variables = variables;
        LoadChildren(Children, this);
        Tag = "window";
    }

    private void LoadChildren(PythonTuple children, Control parent)
    {
        --recursive loading
    }
}
```

Then i want that a class gets information about itself

```
public class UIText : Control
{
    private PythonDictionary Myself
    {
        get
        {
        }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get { MySelf["name"]; }
        set { Myself["name"]; }
    }
    public UIText(Control parent)
    {
        Parent = parent;
        Tag = "text";
    }
}
```

I already know that my info is type of pythontuple because the LoadChildren of UIWindow did load all children from pythontuples, but how do i have reference to myself?

```
private PythonDictionary Myself
{
    get
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Your terminology is a little confusing here. `MySelf` sounds like you want to return `this` but that doesn't make a lot of sense since its a `PythonDictionary`. I'm assuming that the `UIWindow` creates a `UIControl`, with its `Variables`, which if thats what you want to use, you need to pass it into the constructor or a `set` method to set a backing field.

Comment: When i load the children, i can give their PythonDictionary that stores his variables, but i want a direct reference to the UIWindow PythonDictionary variables so when i set some variable on the control, it sets on the UIWindow PyDict variables

Comment: It will do that anyway if you pass the dictionary in, it doesn't make it a copy, it just references the one in the window. The control shouldn't need to reference the window directly. If you want to do that though you can, the `Control` has an `Owner` and `Parent` properties that should reference its containing control (window). You can cast it to a `UIWindow` and reference the `Variables` field.

Comment: Oah, i always tought that creating a variable from a variable was coping and not refering to it...
I need to study a bit more, but yeah you are right!

Thanks

Comment: It copies it for value types (int, double, float, anything of `struct`), but reference types are referenced upon assignment, not copied.

Comment: @RonBeyer To be specific, they are still copying values, it's just that the value being copied is the value of the reference.

Comment: @Kyle Pretty sure that's what I meant by *"but reference types are referenced"*, obviously there is a variable with a pointer to the reference type there which has to be assigned a memory address.